# How to use bad words filter in summernote textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, summernote

I want to make bad words filter but I have a problem with getting this code to work. It works in every other textareas but this one.
After a lot of searching I found that maybe this is because this textarea is with summernote. 
 Any ideas what I should I do? 
 Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea rows="7" name="proposal_desc" placeholder="Въведете описание на предложението си" class="form-control proposal-desc"><?= $d_proposal_desc; ?></textarea>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var triggerWords = ['badword1', 'badword2'];
    $(document).on('keyup', 'textarea', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < triggerWords.length; i++) {
            if ($(this).val().toLowerCase().indexOf(triggerWords[i]) != -1) {
                alert("Alert! You've typed a blocked word.");
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: FYI: this type of check fails when you have a bad word of "ham" and the person types "hamster"

Comment: I assume summernote has an api with event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify our code with mixed of plain JS.

```
const text = "I type badword1 word and will block."

const isBadWord = text.replace(/[\W_]+/g," ").split(' ').includes('badword1')
isBadWord ? alert('Bad word detected!') : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```
var regex = new RegExp('\\b(' + badwords.join('|') + ')\\b', 'i' );
```